# How do I tell who manages the domain when registrar = registrant

Tags: domains, nameserver, whois

I am trying to track down the owner and/or domain host with a view to buying a specific domain. Fairly standard BUT, the registrant name is a person and they are also the registrar. No email details on WHOIS or DNS or Web Info records, website is not active. Any thoughts on how to proceed.

WHOIS also says this:

```
Name servers:
    ns1.googleghs.com
    ns2.googleghs.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer, you can't reveal that data - it's protected and hidden by the registrar of the domain because the person has opt or paid for privacy.

You can only obtain those details by issuing a complaint letter on grounds of copyright i.e DCMA or a legal complaint of another nature. Or [you believe the data may be inaccurate](http://www.icann.org/en/resources/compliance/complaints/whois/privacy-proxy) which is doubtful because you can't see it ;)

You can have [search the domain for history data](http://www.domaintools.com/), it's may be possible to see if the domain has always had privacy added if not, then you may be able to get the information your after.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was afraid of. I might try Facebooking him, is that too stalker-y? The website isn't running and the only thing I can tell about the guy is he has moved houses and has a dissolved company from 4 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to start out at the original [Network Solutions WHOIS database](https://www.networksolutions.com/whois/index.jsp). When I run into a name server for another registrar, I'll go over to that registrar's website. Then I'll look for another WHOIS link on their page, which will search the 2nd registrar's internal database. Sometimes the contact info won't be listed in the 1st registrar's DB, but it will be publicly listed in the 2nd registrar's WHOIS DB. It takes a little bit of sleuthing, but if they haven't paid for a private listing then you might just found out who to contact. It's similar to if they were publicly listed in Network Solutions' WHOIS DB.